# How can this JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

How can this function work for all textboxes when I use

`$('#date, #date2').blur(function () {`

but not when I use

`$('#date').blur(function () {` ?

**MVC Viewer:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ArrivalDateStart, new { id = "date" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ArrivalDateEnd, new { id = "date" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OtherDateEnd, new { id = "date" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OtherDateEnd, new { id = "date" })
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#date, #date2').blur(function () {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var result = "";
        if (date.length === 8) {
            result = result += date.substring(0, 4) + "-" + date.substring(4, 6) + "-" + date.substring(6, 8);
            $(this).val(result);
            $(this).blur()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you have many repeated `id` attributes - this is not valid, and is most likely the cause of the odd behaviour.

Comment: "id" is meant to be unique. HTML/Javascript does unexpected/unpredictable things when it isn't. Use "class" instead if you have a shared ref for more than one element.

Comment: @SDC Mostly it is the fact that the JQ optimiser uses `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` when it detects it has been given a single ID to select.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your elements are meant to have unique IDs. Turn that into a class attribute instead of an ID attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ArrivalDateStart, new { @class = "date" })
```

and select it like this:

```
$('.date').blur(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all id must be unique for one element so you cannot just give `new { id = "date" }` to all of them. But you can give them same className like `new { @class = "date" }` and when you change your selector to ".date" it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have the same id for more then 1 element!
If you set the IDs like date1, date2, date3, ... you can make a selector like:

```
$('textarea[id^="date"]')
```